# tiki-wiki: How to create a tree view category structure?

Tags: tiki-wiki

I have a nested category structure, and each structure has some articles. How can I create a tree view structure of all categories.

- If there is any plugin or module let me know.
- Also if I should code it, please give me a **hint** (or a link to
  documentation) to start coding.
  In addition I don't know why my structure, created by structure feature is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Categories module](http://doc.tiki.org/Module+categories&structure=Documentation+TOC). [Structures](http://doc.tiki.org/Structures&structure=Documentation+TOC) show structure of wiki pages. Not categories.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great, but I don't know why category result in admin page is ok, but in user view of site is empty. Please help me more.

Comment: I handled it! I just granted view permission to categories for anonymous users.